# Is it possible to use getch() to obtain inputs of varying length?

Tags: python, input, getch

I've taken up the adventure of creating a relatively small command-line RPG to flex my newfound Python muscles, but I've already run into a conundrum. I'm using this implementation of getch():

```
def getch():
    fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
    old_settings = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
    tty.setraw(sys.stdin.fileno())
    key = sys.stdin.read(3)
    termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSADRAIN, old_settings)
```

I have `key` set to read in 3 characters to capture arrow keys. Up, for example, is read in as `ESC[A`; with this method, I can use `key[2]` to determine if an arrow key was pressed and which one. All well and good, except that I'd also like to capture all sorts of other keys; `q` for quest log, `wasd` for movement (pressing the arrows in various orders will be the method of attack), and many others. The problem is instantly clear; if `getch()` only returns a single character, arrow functionality is lost entirely.

I'm contemplating rethinking the arrow system altogether if there is no simple solution, but I'm almost certain there must be. Admittedly, I know little of what is going on within `tty`, but I read somewhere that if you only read in 1 character, the excess characters from an arrow press are retained in the buffer. How might I go about accessing said buffer? Alternatively, is there some clever way to tell `stdin` to expect input of variable length?

Thank you in advance for any and all assistance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

don't read three characters.  Read one.

If the one character you just read is `ESC`, read another character or two to see if it was an arrow key or whatever.  If it was a `q`, do the thing for that and then start over.

Comment: That would require the user pressing the arrow key twice, which isn't very friendly.

Comment: no it doesn't.   you replace `read(3)` with `read(1)` followed by an if statement looking for `\x1b` and then `read(2)` to see what key was pressed.

Comment: Ah, yep. Makes perfect sense. Thank you, Token.

Comment: But how to read `ESC` alone? `read(2)` will block in this case until you press other key.

Answer (score 0):

If you consider developing a full game, `PyGame` could also be useful (eventually `ncurses`).

The `getch()` snippet can be upgraded to read arrow key, but how to make the difference between the first char of an arrow key and the `ESC` key? If the user press `ESC`, the solution described will probably wait for the next key press.

I did not find any solution for handling this last case.